# ошибка выполнения на одном из тестов

Tags: c++, testng

Помогите, пожалуйста!  На одном из 14 тестов происходит ошибка выполнения программы. В чем может быть проблема? Задача: После затянувшегося совещания директор фирмы решил заказать такси,чтобы развезти сотрудников по домам. Он заказал N машин —ровно столько, сколь у него сотрудников.Однако когда они подъехали, оказалось, что у каждого водителя такси свой тариф за 1 километр.

Директор знает, какому сотруднику сколько километров от работы до дома (к сожалению, все сотрудники живут в разных направлениях, поэтому нельзя отправить двух сотрудников на одной машине). Теперь директор хочет определить, сколько придется заплатить за перевозку всех сотрудников. Естественно, директор хочет заплатить как можно меньшую сумму.
Вот ссылка на условие http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?chapterid=111162#1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
int i,k,a[104],b[104],x,n2,n,sum;
char  s1[104],s2[104];
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cin.getline(s1,100,'\n'); 
    cin.getline(s2,100,'\n');
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(s1); ++i) 
    {   
        if (isdigit(s1[i])) 
        { 
            x=x*10+int(s1[i])-int('0'); 
        } 
        if ((s1[i]==' ') or (i==strlen(s1)-1)) 
        { 
            ++n; 
            a[n]=x; 
            x=0; 
            for (int j=1; j<=n; j++) 
                if (a[n]<a[j]) 
                    swap(a[n],a[j]); 
        } 
    } 
    n2=0; 
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(s2); ++i) 
    { 
        if (isdigit(s2[i])) 
    { 
        x=x*10+int(s2[i])-int('0'); 
    } 
        if ((s2[i]==' ') or (i==strlen(s2)-1)) 
    { 
        ++n2; 
        b[n2]=x; 
        x=0; 
        for (int j=1; j<=n2; j++) 
        if (b[n2]>b[j]) 
        swap(b[n2],b[j]); 
    } 
    } 

    sum=0; 
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) 
        sum=sum+a[i]*b[i]; 
    cout<<sum;  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот что рекомендуется на сайте - *"Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей."* У вас код без комментариев, без постановки задачи - что вы вообще хотите? Найти любителя разгадывать ребусы в новогоднюю ночь?

Comment: Так тесты скрыты

Comment: Я вас правильно понял? Вам сказали "напишите какую-то программу, а мы ее проверим"? Или было четкое ТЗ? Давайте начнем по списку - *желаемое поведение* - что должна программа делать? Откуда я знаю, верно или нет вы решаете задачу, если вы настолько не уважаете нас, что даже не пишете, какую задачу решаете? Программа не проходит тест или падает на тесте (ошибка выполнения)? Вы понимаете, что ваш вопрос - примерно как где-то спросить у прохожего "я верно иду?", а в ответ на "куда вы идете?" ответить "не ваше дело!" Счастливого Нового года! Постарайтесь в новом году думать и о других...

Comment: @Harry это норма для олимпиадных задач

Comment: @andreymal Я понимаю, чтО норма - что неизвестно? на каком тесте слетает. Но они же дают условие! А ТС его не давала - только исходный текст, по которому нужно было догадываться не только об условии, но и об ограничениях на данные, например!... И, кстати, **опять не приведены никакие ограничения на исходные данные или их формат!**

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva Знаете что, дайте ссылку на сайт, где эта задача... Потому что, например, непонятны ваши странные телодвижения с превращением строки в числа вручную - это что, что-то в условии требует таких извращений? Словом, дайте URL...

Comment: @Harry окей, входные-выходные данные автор действительно не указал почему-то. Но тесты в олимпиадных задачах никогда не дают, максимум один-два ничего не значащих примера

Comment: @andreymal Да блин, я что, к тестам цеплялся? Еще раз и медленно, как для милиционера: **надо давать полное условие задачи**. Лучше с URL, чтоб можно было посмотреть самому. А автор и сейчас дает отрывок из обрывка. Если вам достаточно - отвечайте!

Comment: Всё, добавила ссылку

Answer (score 1):

Лично я думаю, что нужен вот такой код:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int N;
    vector<int> total, dist, cost;
    while(cin >> N) total.push_back(N);
    auto mid = total.begin()+total.size()/2;
    copy(total.begin(),mid,back_inserter(dist));
    copy(mid,total.end(),back_inserter(cost));
    sort(dist.begin(),dist.end(),greater<int>());
    sort(cost.begin(),cost.end());
    cout << inner_product(dist.begin(),dist.end(),cost.begin(),0) << endl;
}
```

Но **без точного ТЗ результат всегда ХЗ!**

Как спросили - такой и ответ...